# Select last inserted id of selected rows in a table

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way for me to select last inserted id from a selected rows. (Not from all the rows in the table) Below is the code I wrote. I want to select one which has the highest value for week attribute. That is the last inserted id of that selected set too.

```
$get_payment_details = 'SELECT * FROM payment WHERE m_id="' . $mselcted_memberI . '" AND app_id= "' . $aprvd_appid . '"';

$get_payment = mysql_query($get_payment_details);
$get_pay_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_payment);
$get_pay_count = mysql_num_rows($get_payment);

if ($get_pay_count < 1) {
    $query1 = "INSERT INTO payment(date,m_id,app_id,week,capital_topay,interest_to_pay,received,advanced,remain_capital,remain_interest)
               VALUES('$date1',"."'".$mselcted_memberI."',"."'".$aprvd_appid."',"."'".$week1."',"."'".$aprvd_amount."',"."'".$ttl_interest."',"."'".$received1."',"."'".$advanced1."',"."'".$aprvd_amount."',"."'".$ttl_interest."')";
    $login_set = mysql_query($query1,$connection);
    confirm_query($login_set);
    echo $week1;
} else if ($get_pay_count >0){

}
```

Comment: `ORDER BY whatever_you_like DESC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: or, alternatively, `SELECT MAX(whatever) FROM table`?

Comment: `mysql_insert_id` — Get the ID generated in the last query ?

Comment: Did any of the answer below help address your issue? If so, you should consider accepting it as correct – it's considered both polite and helpful to do so: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pre-PHP 5.5, you can use [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/mysql_insert_id) to retrieve the last inserted id. From the documentation:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

Note, however, that this function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. The canonically recommended solutions are as follows:

- [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php): use [mysqli_insert_id()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)
- [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php): use [PDO::lastInsertId()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean, but to get the last auto generated id from sql, use

`$theID = mysqli_insert_id();`

Here's more information:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

```
SELECT id FROM payment WHERE yourConditions ORDER BY week DESC LIMIT 0,1;
```